# Node Cannot find module for custom class

Tags: node.js

I've separated some of my methods from my main script into another file:

```
const { GitController } = require('controllers/GitController');

class Controller
{
    constructor() {
        this.git = new GitController();
        this.git.initialize().then(() => {
  
        });
```

`controllers/GitController.js`:

```
const git = require('gulp-git');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

class GitController
{
    constructor() {}
}
```

However i'm getting the following error:

```
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'controllers/GitController'
```

Comment: module.exports = GitController in GitController class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path in your `require` statement is absolute. It should probably be relative, like:

```js
const { GitController } = require('./controller/GitController');
```

From official tutorial:

> If the file starts with "./" it is considered a relative file to the
> file that called require. If the file starts with "/", it is
> considered an absolute path.

https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/

Comment: Thanks, due to my IDE seeing that path I didn't think that was the issue haha